# Transition only one div amongst others using CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a set of `div`'s  which are inserted dynamically into a wrapping `div`.

The end product is something similar to the Dock in OSX.

My question is on How to transition only the div which is under the mouse hover at any instance? Preferably using only CSS.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fm56v) of the problem.

Here is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="dock">
 
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dock{
  display:relative;
  padding:5px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
}

.dock div{
  width:64px;
  height:64px;
  background:black;
  float:left;
  transition: margin-bottom 0.5s;
}
.dock div:hover{
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.dock div:nth-child(n+2){
  margin-left:5px;
}

.dock:after{
  content:"";
  background:green;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  height:42px;
  width:100%;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

**To be clear:**

Right now on hovering over any div, all the four divs transition. My aim is to only transition the div which is hovered on, not all of them.

Comment: Didn't got your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divs are all moving up because they are aligned to the top of their parent element, and you added margin to the bottom of one, expanding the parent.

Consider instead doing this:

```
.dock div{
  width:64px;
  height:64px;
  background:black;
  float:left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: margin-top 0.5s;
}
.dock div:hover{
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

... ie remove margin at the top instead of adding it at the bottom.

Comment: The problem still persists as all the `divs` are transitioning to top. I want only one div to transition on top, the one which is hovered on. Similar to how it happens on the Dock in OSX.

Comment: Did you click 'run' after you edited your jsfiddle? Because the solution I've given does exactly what you asked.

Comment: My bad, I did click on run, but i guess there was a glitch. It works, thanks :)